# Calculated Date filed from another Date field that is Randomised

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have to create some random data and so far with the help of this forum I have done 80% of it but I am now stuck (again)

What I need is this I have a column called Requested Date, this date should randomised but be between 1 and 10 days later than the Order Date. Can this be done?

```
DECLARE @OrderNumber varchar (30)
DECLARE @OrderDate int
DECLARE @OrderLineNumber varchar(50)
DECLARE @CustomerSkey int
DECLARE @ProductSkey int
DECLARE @OrderMethodSkey int
DECLARE @Quantity int
DECLARE @Cost Decimal(18,3)
DECLARE @RequestedDate int

SET @OrderNumber = 1
SET @OrderDate = 0
SET @OrderLineNumber = 1
SET @CustomerSkey = 1
SET @ProductSkey = 1
SET @OrderMethodSkey = 1
SET @Quantity = 1
SET @Cost = 1
SET @RequestedDate = 0


WHILE @OrderNumber <= 100
WHILE @OrderDate <= 100
WHILE @OrderLineNumber <= 100
WHILE @CustomerSkey <= 100
WHILE @ProductSkey <= 100
WHILE @OrderMethodSkey <= 100
WHILE @Quantity <= 100
WHILE @Cost <= 100
WHILE @RequestedDate <= 100


BEGIN
INSERT INTO Orders 
(OrderNumber
, OrderDate
, OrderLineNumber
, CustomerSkey
, ProductSkey
, OrderMethodSkey
, OrderTime
, Quantity
, Cost
, RequestedDate)

SELECT 
'ORD' + Right ('000000' + CAST (@OrderNumber AS varchar (30)), 6)
,DATEADD (day, CAST (RAND () * 1500 as int), '2008-1-1')
,(Right ('0' + CAST (@OrderLineNumber AS varchar (30)), 6))
,(99 * RAND()) + 1
,(99 * RAND()) + 1
,(2 * RAND()) + 1
,DATEADD(ms, cast(86400000 * RAND() as int), convert(time, '00:00'))
,(190 * RAND()) + 10
,(40 * RAND()) + 10
,DATEADD (day, CAST (RAND () * 10 as int), @RequestedDate)




SET @OrderNumber = @OrderNumber + 1
SET @OrderDate = @OrderDate + 1
SET @OrderLineNumber = @OrderLineNumber + 1
SET @CustomerSkey = @CustomerSkey + 1
SET @ProductSkey = @ProductSkey + 1
SET @OrderMethodSkey = @OrderMethodSkey + 1
SET @Quantity = @Quantity + 1
SET @Cost = @Cost + 1
SET @RequestedDate = @RequestedDate + 1

END
```

Comment: Why do you use 9 separate variables when all of them will have identical values or values trivially derivable through simple subtraction or addition?

Comment: Hi Damien I am pretty new to SQL so I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain in layman terms. Ta

Comment: Can you verify that this is in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you can do:

```
with t as (select '2013-01-01'::date as order_date)

select 
   order_date, 
   (order_date + round(.5 + 10*random()) * interval '1 day')::date as requested_date,
   (order_date + round(.5 + 10*random()) * interval '1 day')::date - order_date as difference  from t
```

0) `random()` function returns random number between 0 and 1

1) `round(.5 + 10*random()` will give you number between 1 and 10

2) random number is added to date as an interval in days

3) result is casted to date (because step 2 will return timestamp)

To prove that `round(.5 + 10*random()` gets random number between 1 and 10:

```
with t as (select round(.5 + 10*random()) rnd from generate_series(1,1000000,1))
select rnd, count(*) cnt from t group by rnd order by rnd

rnd      cnt
  1   100249
  2   100817
  3    99550
  4    99813
  5   100065
  6    99468
  7   100089
  8    99652
  9    99889
 10   100408
```

Comment: Hi twn08, how does that fit into my query above?

Comment: @wafw1971 Should give you an algorithm how to solve your problem. In TSQL you will have to use `rand()` function, `dateadd()` function and `round()` function.

Comment: hi twn08, I understand what tools I need to use I just don't know how to write it. ,DATEADD (day, CAST (RAND () * 10 as int), @RequestedDate)

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate the value of order_date before the insert statement

add a new variable with the other declares

```
declare @od datetime
```

inside the while loops but before the insert statement set up the order date

```
select @od = DATEADD (day, CAST (RAND () * 1500 as int), '2008-1-1')
```

use this variable in the insert statement so

```
,DATEADD (day, CAST (RAND () * 1500 as int), '2008-1-1')
```

becomes

```
,@od
```

and use this value to calculate the request date, so
becomes

```
,DATEADD (day, CAST (RAND () * 10 as int), @RequestedDate)
```

and

```
,DATEADD (day, CAST (RAND () * 10 as int), @od)
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b5a00/2)